# Creating a script for usernames

Tags: linux

how do i write a script to create username /passwords for all students in a file called `student_list.txt`.
Passwords should come from a separate file called `passwords.txt`. Check if user running the script is
root before proceeding further in the script. Check whether the files exist before reading records. Also
add all the users to the group `students`.

Comment: Obligatory "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd > student_list.txt` will get you a file created that has a list of all the users and makes a file “student_list.txt”.

Comment: Tell your teacher "Thanks" for the homework assignment idea for me please ...

Answer (score 0):

```
paste student_list.txt passwords.txt  | 
  while read user password; do 
      useradd "$user" && 
         printf '%s\n%s\n' "$password" "$password" | passwd "$user"
  done
```

Suppose `student_list.txt` looks like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and `passwords.txt` looks like:

```
foo_passwd
bar_passwd
baz_passwd
```

paste will transform them it into

```
foo foo_passw
bar bar_passw
baz baz_passw
```

which is easer for the `read` builtin to process in pairs.

Then rest should be self-explanatory. 
`passwd` needs the password twice (confirmation required).

`useradd` also has a `--password` switch, but using STDIN should be more secure.

`adduser` would probably be better instead of `useradd` if you want to satisfy your distro's user policies better.

Comment: What does this do? Can you please provide some input to your answer?

Comment: @Whitecat Done ...

Comment: @PSkocik you can use `adduser --disabled-password` (so it doesn't prompt for a passwd) and then set the password later as you have done above for `useradd`.  Or you can create all the accounts without passwords and then pipe a list of `username:password` (one-per-line) into `chpasswd`, which can do bulk password changes.